# Source shell script automatically in terminal

Tags: shell, terminal, tcsh

How can I automatically source a particular shell script when I open a terminal window by right clicking somewhere and choosing "open in terminal"?

For example, every time I open a terminal I need to run the following command line:

```
source myscript
```

How can I make it so that I don't have to type this automatically?

My script is written in tsch:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
setenv DISPLAY 127.0.0.1:10.0
cd /ast/dcm/data
```

I'm using CentOS 7.

Comment: Every time you open a terminal window or every time you open one by choosing "open in terminal"? The two are probably not the same. What does "open in terminal" do? What file manager are you using? What desktop environment? Is this something you do to open directories or to show the contents of files or to run scripts or what? Also, what is your default shell? Your script is `tcsh`, is that what you use in general?

Comment: @terdon. Thank you. If I right click on the desktop for example and my script on the desktop I need everytime to source my script. My question is: Can I source this script automatically when I open the terminal window from the desktop?

Comment: Yes, probably, but to tell you how, I'll need the answers to my previous questions. The simplest approach would be to add `source ~/myscript` to `~/.bashrc` now that I see you've changed it to `bash`. I'm just not sure what happens when you use this "open in terminal" option. I don't use GUI file managers and you haven't told us which one you are running so it's hard to know.

Comment: I am using File explorer as a file manager and I changed it to bash because it was a mistake. I am sourcing bash script. My desktop env. is Genome

Comment: That's a tcsh script but you talk about bash. Are you running bash or tcsh?

Comment: I fixed it in the question

Comment: +1 for my problem was solved.. i had been trying to run the script e.g.
<bash filename>
<chmod +x script>
and so on.. I simply couldn't run commands in the script like "source" or "export"
now with the "source" command, i can "source" or "export".. what a relief!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how this works with your file manager but, presumably, "open in terminal" is something you use on directories and it just opens a terminal window at that location. If so, it should be enough to source your script from the initialization file for interactive, non-login shells. If you are using `bash`, that is `~/.bashrc` and you need to edit that file and add this line to it:

```
. ~/myscript
```

That assumes that `myscript` is in your `~/`. Now, each time a new shell is started, including when a new terminal is opened, that file will be sourced.

---

Note, however, that the script you show is not a bash script. There is no `setenv` command in bash, that's a C-shell thing. The bash equivalent would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:10.0
cd /ast/dcm/data
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Kindly do you mean that my script sould be like this #!/bin/bash . ~/myscript
setenv DISPLAY 127.0.0.1:10.0
cd /ast/dcm/data

Comment: @MJA I don't understand what you mean. Your script should be exactly as it is. Just put the `. /path/to/script.sh` command in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Also in terminal ===> edit menu ===> profiles preferences ===> title an command tab ===> run a custom command instead of my shel ===> I tried to type source myscript but it did not work?

Comment: @MJA you need to add that line to the `~/.bashrc` file. Come visit the [chat] room if it's still giving you trouble.

Answer (score -1):

In your home Directory :
run `ls -a -l`

- You will see the complete directory structure including the hidden files
- check if there is any file named `.bash_profile`
- if no .bash_profile

  - create a .bash_profile (`touch .bash_profile`)
- `vi .bash_profile`
- Insert your script in the .bash_profile--

  ```
  #!/bin/tcsh
  setenv DISPLAY 127.0.0.1:10.0
  cd /ast/dcm/data
  ```

If you script is right ,when ever you open your terminal and is in the path, where you have created the .bash_profile ,your script will run automatically.

Note:This is LINUX and CentOS

Comment: a tcsh header line in a .bash_profile?